# Issue with media queries - Prevent override of CSS rules

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Initially I had my base CSS and then I added a 640 media query...

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {}
```

I coded everything to fit mobile devices and everything was fine. A little bit ago I added another media query...

```
@media screen and (max-width:840px) {}
```

Now, the mobile part of my site is taking the second media query's code? I don't know a phone that has a max width that large. Why is the 840 media query disturbing my mobile media query?

Comment: Put the second rule first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prevent the override of CSS, use the below code to specify rules only for width between `640px` and `840px`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px) { 
  /* CSS rules for width between 640px and 840px */
}
```

---

Alternatively you can reorder the code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:840px) {} 

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {} /* This will override the above CSS rules */
```

Check out this page: [**MDN Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to learn some good practices.

Answer (score 2):

The Position (order) of the media queries in the .css file plays an important role, they are in ascending priority order (top to bottom ) in the .css file, you just need to change this order as follows:

Put this `@media screen and (max-width:840px) {}` media query, above this one `@media screen and (max-width:640px) {}` and it will fix the issue.

Alternatively you can use the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px) { 
  /* your code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use what manoj said.

This is a guide from [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) - Hope this helps

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```